# Add image logo to Appbar flutter

Tags: flutter, appbar

I am trying to add a logo image to my appbar in flutter but when I try to run the app I get an error. Here is my code:
'''

```
 appBar: AppBar(
                title:
                    Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
              Image.asset('assets/images/Appbar_logo.png',
                  fit: BoxFit.contain, height: 32),
            ])),
```

'''

Here is the error I get:
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
../../third_party/dart/runtime/vm/zone.cc: 94: error: Out of memory.
version=2.10.4 (stable) (Wed Nov 11 13:35:58 2020 +0100) on "windows_x64"
pid=6208, thread=23236, isolate_group=main(0000024760C685E0), isolate=main(0000024760C99A90)
isolate_instructions=7ff6400af230, vm_instructions=7ff6400af240
pc 0x00007ff6402400ec fp 0x0000005eef3fc9f0 Unknown symbol
-- End of DumpStackTrace
[exit     : sp(0) fp(0x5eef3fdb90) pc(0)]
[stub     : sp(0x5eef3fdba0) fp(0x5eef3fdbc0) pc(0x24760581094)]
[dart     : sp(0x5eef3fdbd0) fp(0x5eef3fdc18) pc(0x2476950f3a2) dart:core__RegExp@0150898_hasMatch ]
[dart     : sp(0x5eef3fdc28) fp(0x5eef3fdc78) pc(0x2476b3c9313) package:flutter_tools/src/android/gradle.dart_::*buildGradleApp__async_op_consumeLog ]
[dart     : sp(0x5eef3fdc88) fp(0x5eef3fdcc0) pc(0x2476b3c9cf8) package:flutter_tools/src/base/process.dart__DefaultProcessUtils@76014270_stream__async_op* ]
[dart     : sp(0x5eef3fdcd0) fp(0x5eef3fdd40) pc(0x24769508886) dart:async_::_*rootRunUnary@4048458 ]
[dart     : sp(0x5eef3fdd50) fp(0x5eef3fddb8) pc(0x24769508710) dart:async*::_*rootRunUnary@4048458__rootRunUnary@4048458 ]
[dart     : sp(0x5eef3fddc8) fp(0x5eef3fde60) pc(0x24769508226) dart:async__CustomZone@4048458_runUnary ]
[dart     : sp(0x5eef3fde70) fp(0x5eef3fdef0) pc(0x2476a9aa843) dart:async__CustomZone@4048458_runUnaryGuarded ]
[dart     : sp(0x5eef3fdf00) fp(0x5eef3fdf40) pc(0x2476b3c2355) *dart:async__BufferingStreamSubscription@4048458__sendData@4048458 ]
[dart     : sp(0x5eef3fdf50) fp(0x5eef3fdf80) pc(0x2476a9aa1bd) dart:async__BufferingStreamSubscription@4048458__add@4048458 ]
[dart     : sp(0x5eef3fdf90) fp(0x5eef3fdfc0) pc(0x2476db7e321) dart:async__ForwardingStreamSubscription@4048458__add@4048458 ]
[dart     : sp(0x5eef3fdfd0) fp(0x5eef3fe030) pc(0x2476b3d2198) dart:async__WhereStream@4048458__handleData@4048458 ]
[dart     : sp(0x5eef3fe040) fp(0x5eef3fe078) pc(0x2476db7ded9) dart:async__ForwardingStreamSubscription@4048458__handleData@4048458 ]
[dart     : sp(0x5eef3fe088) fp(0x5eef3fe0b8) pc(0x2476db7dcfb) dart:async__ForwardingStreamSubscription@4048458__handleData@4048458__handleData@4048458 ]
[dart     : sp(0x5eef3fe0c8) fp(0x5eef3fe138) pc(0x24769508886) dart:async*::_*rootRunUnary@4048458 ]
[dart     : sp(0x5eef3fe148) fp(0x5eef3fe1b0) pc(0x24769508710) dart:async*::_*rootRunUnary@4048458__rootRunUnary@4048458 ]
[dart     : sp(0x5eef3fe1c0) fp(0x5eef3fe258) pc(0x24769508226) dart:async__CustomZone@4048458_runUnary ]
[dart     : sp(0x5eef3fe268) fp(0x5eef3fe2e8) pc(0x2476a9aa843) dart:async__CustomZone@4048458_runUnaryGuarded ]
[dart     : sp(0x5eef3fe2f8) fp(0x5eef3fe380) pc(0x24769f0075f) *dart:convert__LineSplitterSink@10003594__addLines@10003594 ]
[dart     : sp(0x5eef3fe390) fp(0x5eef3fe3d8) pc(0x2476db03757) dart:convert__LineSplitterSink@10003594_addSlice ]
[dart     : sp(0x5eef3fe3e8) fp(0x5eef3fe430) pc(0x2476db032ee) dart:convert_StringConversionSinkMixin_add ]
[dart     : sp(0x5eef3fe440) fp(0x5eef3fe498) pc(0x2476a9af3cf) dart:async__SinkTransformerStreamSubscription@4048458__handleData@4048458 ]
[dart     : sp(0x5eef3fe4a8) fp(0x5eef3fe4d8) pc(0x2476a9af1bb) dart:async__SinkTransformerStreamSubscription@4048458__handleData@4048458__handleData@4048458 ]
[dart     : sp(0x5eef3fe4e8) fp(0x5eef3fe558) pc(0x24769508886) dart:async*::_*rootRunUnary@4048458 ]
[dart     : sp(0x5eef3fe568) fp(0x5eef3fe5d0) pc(0x24769508710) dart:async*::_*rootRunUnary@4048458__rootRunUnary@4048458 ]
[dart     : sp(0x5eef3fe5e0) fp(0x5eef3fe678) pc(0x24769508226) dart:async__CustomZone@4048458_runUnary ]
[dart     : sp(0x5eef3fe688) fp(0x5eef3fe708) pc(0x2476a9aa843) dart:async__CustomZone@4048458_runUnaryGuarded ]
[dart     : sp(0x5eef3fe718) fp(0x5eef3fe758) pc(0x2476b3c2355) *dart:async__BufferingStreamSubscription@4048458__sendData@4048458 ]
[dart     : sp(0x5eef3fe768) fp(0x5eef3fe798) pc(0x2476a9aa1bd) dart:async__BufferingStreamSubscription@4048458__add@4048458 ]
[dart     : sp(0x5eef3fe7a8) fp(0x5eef3fe7d8) pc(0x2476a9afea7) dart:async__SinkTransformerStreamSubscription@4048458__add@4048458 ]
[dart     : sp(0x5eef3fe7e8) fp(0x5eef3fe818) pc(0x2476a9afbb6) dart:async__EventSinkWrapper@4048458_add ]
[dart     : sp(0x5eef3fe828) fp(0x5eef3fe858) pc(0x2476a9c5a12) dart:convert__StringAdapterSink@10003594_add ]
[dart     : sp(0x5eef3fe868) fp(0x5eef3fe8a0) pc(0x2476db03061) dart:convert__StringAdapterSink@10003594_addSlice ]
[dart     : sp(0x5eef3fe8b0) fp(0x5eef3fe900) pc(0x2476db01049) dart:convert__Utf8ConversionSink@10003594_addSlice ]
[dart     : sp(0x5eef3fe910) fp(0x5eef3fe958) pc(0x2476cffff1e) dart:convert__Utf8ConversionSink@10003594_add ]
[dart     : sp(0x5eef3fe968) fp(0x5eef3fe998) pc(0x2476a9af6b6) dart:convert__ConverterStreamEventSink@10003594_add ]
[dart     : sp(0x5eef3fe9a8) fp(0x5eef3fea00) pc(0x2476a9af3cf) dart:async__SinkTransformerStreamSubscription@4048458__handleData@4048458 ]
[dart     : sp(0x5eef3fea10) fp(0x5eef3fea40) pc(0x2476a9af1bb) dart:async__SinkTransformerStreamSubscription@4048458__handleData@4048458__handleData@4048458 ]
[dart     : sp(0x5eef3fea50) fp(0x5eef3feac0) pc(0x24769508886) dart:async*::_*rootRunUnary@4048458 ]
[dart     : sp(0x5eef3fead0) fp(0x5eef3feb38) pc(0x24769508710) dart:async*::**rootRunUnary@4048458__rootRunUnary@4048458 ]
[dart     : sp(0x5eef3feb48) fp(0x5eef3febe0) pc(0x24769508226) dart:async__CustomZone@4048458_runUnary ]
[dart     : sp(0x5eef3febf0) fp(0x5eef3fec70) pc(0x2476a9aa843) dart:async__CustomZone@4048458_runUnaryGuarded ]
[dart     : sp(0x5eef3fec80) fp(0x5eef3fecc0) pc(0x2476b3c2355) *dart:async__BufferingStreamSubscription@4048458__sendData@4048458 ]
[dart     : sp(0x5eef3fecd0) fp(0x5eef3fed00) pc(0x2476a9aa1bd) dart:async__BufferingStreamSubscription@4048458__add@4048458 ]
[dart     : sp(0x5eef3fed10) fp(0x5eef3fed40) pc(0x2476a9a9f36) dart:async__SyncStreamController@4048458__sendData@4048458 ]
[dart     : sp(0x5eef3fed50) fp(0x5eef3fed80) pc(0x2476a9a7a6a) dart:async__StreamController@4048458__add@4048458 ]
[dart     : sp(0x5eef3fed90) fp(0x5eef3fedc0) pc(0x2476a9a76fb) dart:async__StreamController@4048458_add ]
[dart     : sp(0x5eef3fedd0) fp(0x5eef3fee10) pc(0x2476a9aabd2) dart:io__Socket@15069316__onData@15069316 ]
[dart     : sp(0x5eef3fee20) fp(0x5eef3fee50) pc(0x2476a9aa9cb) dart:io__Socket@15069316__onData@15069316__onData@15069316 ]
[dart     : sp(0x5eef3fee60) fp(0x5eef3feed0) pc(0x247695089af) dart:async*::**rootRunUnary@4048458 ]
[dart     : sp(0x5eef3feee0) fp(0x5eef3fef48) pc(0x24769508710) dart:async*::__rootRunUnary@4048458__rootRunUnary@4048458 ]
[dart     : sp(0x5eef3fef58) fp(0x5eef3feff0) pc(0x24769508226) dart:async__CustomZone@4048458_runUnary ]
[dart     : sp(0x5eef3ff000) fp(0x5eef3ff080) pc(0x2476a9aa843) dart:async__CustomZone@4048458_runUnaryGuarded ]
[dart     : sp(0x5eef3ff090) fp(0x5eef3ff0d0) pc(0x2476b3c2355) *dart:async__BufferingStreamSubscription@4048458__sendData@4048458 ]
[dart     : sp(0x5eef3ff0e0) fp(0x5eef3ff110) pc(0x2476a9aa1bd) dart:async__BufferingStreamSubscription@4048458__add@4048458 ]
[dart     : sp(0x5eef3ff120) fp(0x5eef3ff150) pc(0x2476a9a9f36) dart:async__SyncStreamController@4048458__sendData@4048458 ]
[dart     : sp(0x5eef3ff160) fp(0x5eef3ff190) pc(0x2476a9a7a6a) dart:async__StreamController@4048458__add@4048458 ]
[dart     : sp(0x5eef3ff1a0) fp(0x5eef3ff1d0) pc(0x2476a9a76fb) dart:async__StreamController@4048458_add ]
[dart     : sp(0x5eef3ff1e0) fp(0x5eef3ff210) pc(0x2476a9a9d73) dart:io__RawSocket@15069316__RawSocket@15069316.* ]
[dart     : sp(0x5eef3ff220) fp(0x5eef3ff280) pc(0x24769558a1c) dart:core__Closure@0150898_dyn_call ]
[dart     : sp(0x5eef3ff290) fp(0x5eef3ff2d0) pc(0x2476a985a2d) dart:io__NativeSocket@15069316_issueReadEvent_issue ]
[dart     : sp(0x5eef3ff2e0) fp(0x5eef3ff318) pc(0x247695058c3) dart:async*::_*microtaskLoop@4048458 ]
[dart     : sp(0x5eef3ff328) fp(0x5eef3ff358) pc(0x24769505524) dart:async*::_*startMicrotaskLoop@4048458 ]
[dart     : sp(0x5eef3ff368) fp(0x5eef3ff388) pc(0x2476950543b) dart:async*::_*startMicrotaskLoop@4048458__startMicrotaskLoop@4048458 ]
[dart     : sp(0x5eef3ff398) fp(0x5eef3ff3c8) pc(0x247695052f3) dart:isolate*::__runPendingImmediateCallback@1026248 ]
[dart     : sp(0x5eef3ff3d8) fp(0x5eef3ff3f0) pc(0x24763a3032d) dart:isolate__RawReceivePortImpl@1026248__handleMessage@1026248 ]
[entry    : sp(0x5eef3ff400) fp(0x5eef3ff518) pc(0x24760581598)]

Answer (score 0):

I changed this line:

'''
fit: BoxFit.contain, height: 32),
to this
fit: BoxFit.cover, height: 32),
'''

and it works now.